# Docker - Safest way to upload new content to production

Tags: docker, backup, restore, volumes

I am new to Docker.
Every time i need to upload new content in production I get anxious that something will go wrong so I try to understand how backups work and how to backup my Volumes which seems pretty complicated for me at the moment.

So i have this idea of creating a new image every time I want to upload new content.
Then i pull this image in the machine and stack rm/deploy the container and see if it works - if not I pull the old image.
If the code works I can then delete my old image.
Is this a proper/safe way to update production machines or I need to get going with backups and restores?
I mean i read this guide https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-backup-and-restore-docker-containers/ but I don't quite understand how to restore my volumes.

Any suggestion would be nice.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

That's a pretty normal way to use Docker.  Make sure you give each build a distinct tag, like a date stamp or source-control ID.  You can do an upgrade like

```sh
# CONTAINER=...
# IMAGE=...
# OLD_TAG=...
# NEW_TAG=...

# Shell function to run `docker run`
start_the_container() {
  docker run ... --name "$CONTAINER" "$IMAGE:$1"
}

# Shut down the old container
docker stop "$CONTAINER"
docker rm "$CONTAINER"

# Launch the new container
start_the_container "$NEW_TAG"

# Did it work?
if check_if_container_started_successfully; then
  # Delete the old image
  docker rmi "$IMAGE:$OLD_TAG"
else
  # Roll back
  docker stop "$CONTAINER"
  docker rm "$CONTAINER"
  start_the_container "$OLD_TAG"
  docker rmi "$IMAGE:$NEW_TAG"
fi
```

The only `docker run` command here is in the `start_the_container` shell function; if you have environment-variable or volume-mount settings you can put them there, and the old volumes will get reattached to the new container.  You do need to back up volume content, but that can be separate from this upgrade process.  You should not need to back up or restore the contents of the container filesystems beyond this.

If you're using Kubernetes, changing the `image:` in a Deployment spec does this for you automatically.  It will actually start the new container(s) before stopping the old one(s) so you get a zero-downtime upgrade; the key parts to doing this are being able to identify the running containers, and connecting them to a load balancer of some sort that can route inbound requests.

The important caveat here is that you must *not* use Docker volumes or bind mounts for key parts of your application.  Do not use volumes for your application code, or static asset files, or library files.  Otherwise the lifecycle of the volume will take precedence over the lifecycle of the image/container, and you'll wind up running old code and can't update things this way.  (They make sense for pushing config files in, reading log files out, and storing things like the underlying data for your database.)